# Why is this React method not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have some code that is meant to eliminate placeholders onFocus and return them onBlur, it seems to work properly for the login text input, but not for the password one. Do you mind having a look at the code?

This is the method in question:

```js
togglePlaceholder = (nodeType:string,localStateValue:string) => {
    switch (eval(`this.state.${localStateValue}`)) {
        case nodeType:
            return this.setState({[localStateValue]:null});
        case null:
            return this.setState({[localStateValue]:nodeType});
    }
}
```

I'm using eval here because I'm planning to reuse this function across multiple components to toggle their local state.

These are the components:

```
<TextInput style={styles.logInFormInput}
    placeholder={this.state.logInPlaceholder}
    onFocus={()=>this.togglePlaceholder('login','logInPlaceholder')}
    onBlur={()=>this.togglePlaceholder('login','logInPlaceholder')}
></TextInput>

<TextInput style={styles.logInFormInput}
    secureTextEntry={true}
    placeholder={this.state.passwordPlaceholder}
    onFocus={()=>this.togglePlaceholder('password','passwordPlaceholder')}
    onBlur={()=>this.togglePlaceholder('password','passwordPlaceholder')}
></TextInput>
```

Seems to be working properly for login, but not password.

Comment: A side comment, but eval seems unnecessary and confusing. Why not `switch (this.state[localStateValue]) {...`?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see what actually happens in the password case?

Comment: Use a custom component and you can achieve this much easier: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-moore-5oy6b (browser version)

Comment: If your state 
`this.state = {logInPlaceholder: "login", passwordPlaceholder: "password"};`
looks like this it should be working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are just hiding or showing I think you could use a pivot of thinking to solve this a little easier :)

The simplest way in my mind to would be to track the id of the currently focused element and use it to conditionally render the placeholder:

```
<TextInput onFocus={() => setActive(id)} onBlur={clearActive} placeholder={this.state.activeId === id ? 'placeholder' : ''} />
```

It would be simple to create a HoC which manages the inputs within, allowing you to group it accordingly